# Android Firebase Invites app description not localized

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-invites

The app description included to the invitation email automatically is not localized. Looks like independently on a device, account language an app description included to an email is in English. Am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't it be localized automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like indeed the app description included to an invitation letter is not localized.

It's possible to customize the invitation email by [setEmailHtmlContent (String htmlContent)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/appinvite/AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder#setEmailHtmlContent(java.lang.String)) which content could be localized.